# Google Sites: Clicking link mailto: my.name@domain.com does not open gmail anymore

Tags: gmail, google-sites

Clicking link mailto: my.name@domain.com on my Google Site does not open gmail anymore. Has something changed? Thanks for information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that which browser you are using. May be it's a browser specific problem.

Check with different browsers to see if it's same for all.

Also, try this link. It may help you -

http://googlesystem.blogspot.in/2012/02/open-mailto-links-using-gmail-in-google.html

Comment: I managed to make it work on firefox like explained here: http://googlesystem.blogspot.fi/2009/06/set-gmail-as-default-email-client-in.html but where can I set Gmail as Default Email Client in Chrome?

Comment: I also read this http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10966 but everything seems to be ok... A couple of weeks everything worked ok in all browsers... something strange has happened... I have no idea. :-(

Comment: As mentioned - "If you want to set Gmail as the default mail client for your computer and not just for Firefox, install Google Talk, Gmail Notifier for Windows or Google Notifier for Mac." Have you checked doing that?

Comment: I found the place! http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1382847 Thx for helping! :-) But its unclear for me why this changed on its own. As I mentioned it worked before fine. But anyway, case closed.

Comment: when you go to Gmail in **Chrome**, you will be asked if you want Gmail to open all email links. Say yes, and clicking on email links in any application on your computer will open a fresh Gmail compose window.